# How to unbind window when click anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I unbind the window when clicking an anchor tag with a unique ID? I am trying to use beforeunload so that when a user tries to navigate away from the page, they get a prompt asking to confirm they want to do so, but there is an anchor tag on the page that I would like to have not make this occur when clicked. It currently pops up the alert box because of navigating away from the page, but I want to create an exception for this anchor tag. How would I do this? I have tried unbinding onbeforeunload when a user clicks the anchor tag, but I believe my code might be wrong. any suggestions as to a fix for this? I do not understand binding and unbinding very well, so please be patient with me. 
Thanks.

this is the code for what I am trying to do:

```
 $('#catshopbuy').click(function(){
        $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});
```

Rest of the jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target.href) $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(event) {
    $('div.offerWindow').css("visibility", "visible");
    return 'Press "Stay on Page" and get a special offer!';
});

$('#catshopbuy').click(function(){
        $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});
```

Comment: And you want to bind it again if you click somewhere else?

Comment: @putvande It shouldn't matter as if they click on that anchor tag it takes them from what is a shopping cart to the checkout page. As it stands, I want them to get the alert box when they either close the page or refresh, when they click on the anchor tag, it should just bring them to another page.

Comment: What if you trigger click event on the 'OK' button of the confirmation popup when the anchor tag is clicked!!

Answer (score 1):

It should be `$(window).unbind('beforeunload');`.

So something like this:

```
$(function() {
     $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
          return 'Press "Stay on Page" and get a special offer!';
     });

     $('#catshopbuy').click(function(){
         $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
     });
});
```

Comment: I have updated my code to reflect your solution, but it does not seem to be working. Do I need these to blocks of code wrapped in the function to make it work?

Comment: I have put it between the `$(function(){` because that is triggered when the document is done loading and your link will be available for the code.